# Rewriting URL over a file .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is my problem.
I know how to rewrite a URL only if the file doesn't exist.
But I came across a problem that I have never encountered before.

Given the URL : http://www.my-host.com/agences/my-agencies

With at the directory root 2 files :

- agences.php
- .htaccess

In the .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^agences/(.*) /agences.php?agence=$1
```

This does not redirect to the /agences.php and is not even interpreted.
If I change the **RewriteRule** by:

```
RewriteRule ^agences/(.*) $1
```

It doesn't even process the rewrite rules.
And so even if I prepend the slash to the regex condition like this :

```
RewriteRule ^/agences/(.*) $1
```

I run on an apache 2.4.10, with the **AllowOverride** all configure in the vhost.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you getting a 404 error when you request /agences/ ?

Comment: Yes, if i hit the `http://www.my-host.com/agences/` i get 404 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add that at the beginning of the code:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

> The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a
>   request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and
>   /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory
>   looking for files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map
>   which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and
>   content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of
>   them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's
>   requirements. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/content-negotiation.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didn't notice that the MultiViews options could be a problem in the mod_rewrite